# Unbalanced parenthesis error with Python and the library re

Tags: python, href, python-re

I want to remove my `href`s to my dataset but I get this error: "Unbalanced parenthesis"!
To remove the "href", I use this following python code:

```py
data = data.apply(lambda x: re.sub(re.findall(r'\<a(.*?)\>', x)[0], '', x) if (len(re.findall(r'\<a (.*?)\>', x))>0) and ('href' in re.findall(r'\<a (.*?)\>', x)[0]) else x)
```

And after this application, I get this following error :

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4211             else:
   4212                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4213                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4214 
   4215         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-25-55819437c264> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 data = data.apply(lambda x: re.sub(re.findall(r'\<a(.*?)\>', x)[0], '', x) if (len(re.findall(r'\<a (.*?)\>', x))>0) and ('href' in re.findall(r'\<a (.*?)\>', x)[0]) else x)
      2 if verbose: print('#'*10 ,'Step - Remove hrefs:'); check_vocab(data, local_vocab)

/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    189     a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
    190     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 191     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    192 
    193 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py in _compile(pattern, flags)
    299     if not sre_compile.isstring(pattern):
    300         raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
--> 301     p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
    302     if not (flags & DEBUG):
    303         if len(_cache) >= _MAXCACHE:

/usr/lib/python3.6/sre_compile.py in compile(p, flags)
    560     if isstring(p):
    561         pattern = p
--> 562         p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
    563     else:
    564         pattern = None

/usr/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py in parse(str, flags, pattern)
    867     if source.next is not None:
    868         assert source.next == ")"
--> 869         raise source.error("unbalanced parenthesis")
    870 
    871     if flags & SRE_FLAG_DEBUG:

error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 36
```

I have any idea for to solve this problem after many hours of practice.

Comment: Independent of the regex, try [`data.str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) instead of the `.apply()` pattern

Comment: That's way too much going on for a lambda. Extract the logic to a proper function so we can see it.

Comment: FYI you don't need to escape `<` and `>` in regexp.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `re.sub()` is a regular expression. The strings returned by `re.findall()` is not a regular expression, they're strings found in `x`. It would be quite a coincidence if this happened to be a valid regexp and it also matched what you want.

If you want to replace all the `<a ...>`, just use that as the regexp argument in `re.sub()`. Then there's no need for the conditional to check if the expression matches; if it doesn't, `re.sub()` will just return the string unchanged.

You should also check for a space after `<a`, otherwise you'll match any tag whose name begins with `a`.

```
data = data.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'<a\s.*?>', '', x, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

But as mentioned in a comment, pandas has a built-in regexp replacement operation.

```
data = data.str.replace(r'<a\s.*?>', '', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You code contains

```
re.sub(re.findall(...))
```

`re.findall` as of the documentation does the following:

> Return a list of all non-overlapping matches in the string.

but `re.sub` expects a pattern as its first argument, but is getting a string containing html. That's why it throws a regex-compile-error.

Comment: They're using `[0]` to get the first element of the list.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you are correct. **Thanks.** But it is still a string containing `html`. So won't work either. Changed my answer though.

Comment: Hello, skyrocketer. Are you trying to hunt for reputation?

Comment: Isn't everyone hunting for reputation in some way? :D Is something wrong with that?

Comment: No. People aren't hunting for reputation (most people). see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126987/what-is-rep-farming